# How does getting the application reference from a service work in Android?

Tags: android, service, frameworks

I have a local `Service` running together with my application. I also have a class derrived from `Application` class.

When the local service is created it gets and uses the `Application` instance using `getApplication`.

Can the app itself be terminated while my service is still running and what happens if so? Would `getApplication` return null?

Regards Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can the app itself be terminated while
>   my service is still running

No.